# Framework contains code references to another framework

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I distribute a framework and recently added functionality that requires a third-party framework.  I would love to be able to embed that other framework in my own framework, but "umbrella" frameworks are frowned upon by Apple.

It would suffice for my users (developers) to deal with the dependency my framework has and take care of including the other framework in their project.

But if I try to build my framework without the other framework embedded, it won't compile because I have code references to the module.

How do I get around that?

Comment: I compiled `opencv` as Xcode framework without opencl and blas support, and my code compiles only when I also link `Accelerate` and `OpenCL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to make the third-party framework project a dependent sub-project to my framework project.  I'll leverage dependency managers to make it so the developer users of my framework don't have to deal with downloading and integrating the third-party framework.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a perfect use case for [Frameworks and Weak Linking](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/WeakLinking.html).
Specifically, you would make linking of the framework optional in the `Build Phases-> Link Binary With Librares` of your target.
Here, you are essentially delegating the responsibility to link to required frameworks to your client.

In your code, before using any symbols of the optional framework you must check the presence of the framework by using `if([<Framework> class])`.

Comment: Thanks Puneet.  I monkeyed around with that approach but to no avail.  In particular, it seems impossible to test for symbols in the case of something like delegation protocol references.  Instead, I tried creating a new set of projects from scratch, and this time made the third-party framework project a dependent sub-project, and it is compiling now.  I had read elsewhere people saying something to the effect of "let CocoaPods" handle this type of thing for you, and now I believe they're right.  Will get setup with SPM or other dependency manager.  Again, thank you sir!